# Cannot deploy to GAE -- .jsp file won't compile

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment

I've looked over and tried everything I can find about an inability to successfully compile .jsp files prior to deployment to GAE.

- I've uninstalled and reinstalled Eclipse (Kepler)
- I've uninstalled and reinstalled the GAE Eclipse Plugin (1.8.8) for Eclipse 4.3
- I've uninstalled and reinstalled JDK1.7.0_45 (both 32-bit and 64-bit)
- I've removed all JREs from my system.
- The "Deploy to App Engine..." menu-item in the 'g' tool apparently does not use the appcfg.cmd file because modifying it has no effect at all.
- I've added specific JDK VMs to eclipse.ini
- I've copied tools.java from the JDK into the appengine SDK (1.8.8)
- I've tried running appcfg.cmd from a cmd shell

I can run in the dev server just fine, but I can't find a way to deploy because I cannot compile my one .jsp file.  Apparently there is no java compiler found no matter what I do.

I know this has been discussed over and over again.  I've tried what I've found online over and over again to no avail.  I find the error logs less than useful.

The deploy command executed is (which uses my JDK):

```
Error while executing: C:\jdk1.7.0_45_32\bin\javaw.exe -classpath /C:/eclipse-kepler32/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/impl/appengine-api-labs.jar;/C:/eclipse-kepler32/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/impl/appengine-api-stubs.jar;/C:/eclipse-kepler32/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/impl/appengine-api.jar;/C:/eclipse-kepler32/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/impl/appengine-local-runtime.jar;/C:/eclipse-kepler32/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/impl/google_sql.jar;C:\eclipse-kepler32\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8\lib\shared\appengine-local-runtime-shared.jar;C:\eclipse-kepler32\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8\lib\shared\el-api.jar;C:\eclipse-kepler32\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar;C:\eclipse-kepler32\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar;C:\eclipse-kepler32\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar;C:\eclipse-kepler32\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar;C:\eclipse-kepler32\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar;C:\eclipse-kepler32\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8\lib\shared\jsp-api.jar;C:\eclipse-kepler32\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8\lib\shared\servlet-api.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\classes;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\1384945950039-0;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-labs.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-endpoints-deps.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-endpoints.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-jsr107cache-1.8.8.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-testing.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\asm-4.0.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-beanutils.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-collections.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-appengine-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-api-client-1.16.0-rc.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-api-client-appengine-1.16.0-rc.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-api-client-servlet-1.16.0-rc.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-api-services-oauth2-v2-rev50-1.16.0-rc.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-http-client-1.16.0-rc.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-http-client-appengine-1.16.0-rc.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-http-client-gson-1.16.0-rc.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-http-client-jackson-1.16.0-rc.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-http-client-jackson2-1.16.0-rc.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-oauth-client-1.16.0-rc.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-oauth-client-appengine-1.16.0-rc.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-oauth-client-java7-1.15.0-rc.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-oauth-client-jetty-1.11.0-beta.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-oauth-client-servlet-1.16.0-rc.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\gson-2.1.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\guava-14.0.1.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\gwt-servlet.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\iText-2.1.7.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\itext-pdfa-5.4.4.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\iText-rtf-2.1.7.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\itext-xtra-5.4.4.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\itextpdf-5.4.4.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-core-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jdo-api-3.0.1.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jetty-6.1.11.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jetty-util-6.1.11.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jfreechart-client.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jide-common-client.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jnlp-servlet.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jsr107cache-1.1.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jstl.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jta-1.1.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\objectify-4.0rc2.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\poi-3.6-20091214.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\poi-contrib-3.6-20091214.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\poi-ooxml-3.6-20091214.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.6-20091214.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\poi-scratchpad-3.6-20091214.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jakarta-jstl-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jakarta-standard-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-jdt-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\standard.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\tools.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\transaction-api-1.1.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\ulc-core-server.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\ulc-deployment-key.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\ULCOfficeIntegration-server-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\xpp3-1.1.4c.jar; com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC -uriroot C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp -p org.apache.jsp -l -v -webinc C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7613380766126120775.tmp\WEB-INF\generated_web.xml -d C:\Users\tmcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\1384945950039-0 -javaEncoding UTF-8
```

Can someone from Google give me any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Tony Carter
(tmcarter54@gmail.com or tony.m.carter@tmcarter-engg.com)

Comment: What's in your JSP file? any incorrect imports or code that might fail to compile?

Answer (score 0):

Three suggestions:

1. Try using the command-line tools (i.e., appfcfg). They'll give you a better error message than `Error while executing`.
2. Post a small .jsp that demonstrates the problem.
3. If for some reason you can't do #2, set up a test app. Starting with the simplest possible .jsp, extend it in the direction of your current .jsps until you see the problem occur. Alternatively you could trim back your current .jsps until they work, but starting from something simple and working forward might be a quick way of uncovering the problem.

Comment: I figured this out before the responses were posted -- I had to remove the old eclipse plugin which contained a compiler that wasn't compatible with the newer SDK but was chosen through the system PATH environment variable.